# Database access in Android - what is the optimal moment for saving data

Tags: java, android, database

I´ve written a Quiz app where I want to add a score for right and wrong answers.

My problem is that I don't know what the best moment for saving the data is. Writing the current score after each question is too resource-intensive, isn´t it?

Is there any way to save them when the user closes the app?

Comment: Do it in a worker thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should persist your data onPause() and restore it onResume().

Also see http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html